# Streamsets class not found exception

Tags: apache-kafka, hadoop-streaming, streamsets

I built a pipeline in streamsets to read data from my sql and do change data capture. When i started the execution of the pipeline i get the following error.

Pipeline Status: START_ERROR: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/KafkaException

Comment: I see you joined the StreamSets Slack channel - that's a better place to interact. From your profile I see you're at MapR. Did you carefully follow the MapR-specific instructions at https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/#Installation/MapR-Prerequisites.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely problem is that you need to follow the MapR-specific instructions at https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/#Installation/MapR-Prerequisites.html

Comment: The issue is resolved after reinstalling the right version of streamsets and veryfying the prerequisites.

Comment: Great! Could you mark this answer as correct if it pointed you in the right direction?